# Which crypto libararies support Format-Preserving Encryption (FPE)?

Tags: encryption

Is there any open source [FPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) implementation available? I am no cryptography expert but I am aware of the basic concepts behind FPE and I am looking for a generic library which helps me implement FPE for sensitive data such as phone numbers, social security numbers, etc. No strong programming language preference, but robustness of the algorithm and implementation are important.

What I found so far:

- [libffx](https://github.com/kpdyer/libffx) (implements [FFX](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ffx/ffx-spec.pdf) in Python, [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html) license)
- [botan](http://botan.randombit.net/manual/fpe.html) (implements [FE1](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/251) in C++, [BSD2](http://botan.randombit.net/license.html) license)
- [Miracl](http://www.certivox.com/miracl) (implements [BPS](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/bps/bps-spec.pdf) in C/C++, dual licensing: commercial or [AGPL](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/AGPL-3.0))

but I did not yet personally use them.

Are there any other libraries supporting FPE, or will be in the near future? Which of these or others are recommended and why?

Comment: The most important thing to know about FPE (which is inherently deterministic) is that you should avoid it in favour of semantically secure encryption whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, but let's assume for now that there are suitable applications of FPE.

Comment: The Mysto FPE libraries at https://github.com/mysto provide java, node.js and python implementations of the draft NIST standard for FF3-1 and incorporate and pass the NIST test vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and extendable library on Python https://github.com/emulbreh/pyffx